# callback on first/last visible item changed in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a view that will update itself based on what currently shown as first(or last) item in the `RecyclerView`. Is there a way to register listener that gets notified when that happen? I can only find `findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()` that might be useful but this isn't a callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` to be notified any time the RecyclerView is scrolled, and you can use `getChildAt()` with `getChildViewHolder()` to retrieve the top/bottom views and their respective ViewHolders:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView top = findViewById(R.id.top);
    final TextView bottom = findViewById(R.id.bottom);
    final RecyclerView recycler = findViewById(R.id.recycler);

    recycler.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
    recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recycler.setAdapter(new MyAdapter());
    recycler.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            View firstChild = recycler.getChildAt(0);
            MyViewHolder topHolder = (MyViewHolder) recycler.getChildViewHolder(firstChild);
            top.setText("Topmost visible view: " + topHolder.value);

            View lastChild = recycler.getChildAt(recycler.getChildCount() - 1);
            MyViewHolder bottomHolder = (MyViewHolder) recycler.getChildViewHolder(lastChild);
            bottom.setText("Bottommost visible view: " + bottomHolder.value);
        }
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: sorry I was busy and totally forgot about this. I just tried it and worked well. thanks for your idea!

Answer (score 2):

Class responsible for laying out views in `RecyclerView` is `RecyclerView.LayoutManager`.

You can override it and add some extra code to methods responsible for positioning the views. Assuming you're using a vertical `LinearLayoutManager` (in Kotlin):

```
recyclerView.layoutManager = object : LinearLayoutManager(this){
    override fun onLayoutCompleted(state: RecyclerView.State?) {
        super.onLayoutCompleted(state)
        // triggered when there's a re-layout (item added/removed etc)
        Log.d("LMDebug", "layout "+findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition())
    }

    override fun offsetChildrenVertical(dy: Int) {
        super.offsetChildrenVertical(dy)
        // triggered during scroll
        Log.d("LMDebug", "offset "+findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition())
    }
}
```

Just replace logs with whatever you need.